# Value is not retrieved from database in sqlite in iphone

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I am now doing one program in SQLite. I have to save three data name,description(desc) and salary.After that these data have to be displayed in text fields for further updates. Below is my code for displaying

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tblView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}

switch(indexPath.section) {
    case 0:
        cell.text = empObj.name;

        break;
    case 1:
        cell.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", empObj.desc];
        break;

    case 2:
        cell.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", empObj.salary];
        break;
}

return cell;
}
```

Below is the code for saving data in the database:

```
(void) saveAllData {

if(isDirty) {

    if(updateStmt == nil) {
        const char *sql = "update EMP1 Set name = ?,desc=?, salary = ? Where empID = ?";
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &updateStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK) 
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating update statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }

    sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 1, [name UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);

    sqlite3_bind_text(updateStmt, 2, [desc UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_double(updateStmt, 3, [salary doubleValue]);
    sqlite3_bind_int(updateStmt, 4, empID);

    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(updateStmt))
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while updating. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

    sqlite3_reset(updateStmt);

    isDirty = NO;
}

//Reclaim all memory here.
[name release];
name = nil;

[desc release];
desc = nil;
[salary release];
salary = nil;

isDetailViewHydrated = NO;
}
```

But that description(desc) is showing `null`. If I edit the `desc` variable and save, then it shows. But if I close the program and then reopen it, then in details part the description(desc) value is coming `null`.

Please help.

Comment: put the breakpoints and debug your code

Comment: I got a [link as a tutorial](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-a-todo-list-using-sqlite-part-1/), take a look.May be helpful to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see where you opened the database

make sure you opened it !!

I suggest that you try to use

```
const char * update= [[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"UPDATE EMP1  SET name ='%@',desc='%@',salary=%d WHERE empID = %d",name,desc,salary,empID] UTF8String];
        sqlite3_exec(db, update, nil, nil, nil);
```

Let me Know if it helps!!!

Comment: Ya, I opened database. I got my result. Thank you for your help.